# Having problems with these very simple things on HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am very new to this and have a very hard time understanding my lecturer (who unfortunately helps me very little)

This is my assignment (image below). It's a mock up clothing website and my desired layout is on the left, whereas my current progress is on the right. This is my first ever attempt at HTML/CSS so if you could please help me out that would make me a happy man!

- Paragraphing the categories like I have to the right
- Aligning the black text boxes with the photos above them
- Floating the titles on the left, with the paragraphs to the right. (I have tried multiple things with this but to no avail)
- Also, I put `<h1>` for each heading but they aren't going to that size?

  [image: - Please see this picture for reference]

Comment: Did you try anything yourself yet?

Comment: The best thing to do is to get some basic understanding of HTML and CSS. You will gain a lot more knowledge that way, instead of letting us to all the heavy lifting!:) Tell your lecturer that you need some time to learn this. He should understand imo.

Comment: My first HTML assignment was a lot easier than that.

Comment: You can learn HTML/CSS in 30 days... it`s not hard to learn. For example here: http://htmlandcssbook.com

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a very specific question. Please re-post your question, and include your existing code. (preferably you should only include enough code to re-create the problem, without including all your code) Also, please focus on one problem at a time. It seems that these may be *separate* questions about the same page, each regarding different parts of the code.

Comment: As the question stands, it will probably be closed, primarily because you didn't include 'what you tried', and 'what you expected would happen' when you tried what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

using CSS you can set "position: absolute" then use something like "left:100px;"

that is assuming your div tags are correctly set up (or set up in general) from your last statement "Also, I put for each heading but they aren't going to that size?" it seems that your div id, or class id's are incorrectly labelled.

Comment: That hardly answers the question. (Although to be fair, this is not a question fit for SO anyway.)

Comment: I agree with you, but if this is homework then its a form of cheating as he/she is not looking for the answer as much as expecting someone to give them the answer on a plate. Learning programming can be challenging but if you copy and paste peoples code you are no more a programmer than a parrot is a talker.

Comment: Yes, but just throwing “absolute positioning” into the ring is hardly an answer.

Comment: In my opinion absolute positioning is a possible solution to the authors problem, i only mentioned it so the author would look into it and see whether that would be an approach he/she may like to take.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend taking a look at http://jsfiddle.net/

It's very possibly the single most useful tool I've ever encountered for css/html/javascript testing/editing/learning. (short of something like Dreamweaver, I suppose).

There are plenty of good tutorials around on how to use it, but it'll really let you toy with little options along the learning process, and will help you 'teach yourself' when things get rough with the teacher.